# What is the achievement in Making History 2?

Tags: achievements, making-history-ii

In Making History 2: The War of the World, there is only one Steam achievement, and no information is listed about it on Steam.

What is the one "secret" achievement, and how do I unlock it?

Answer (score 1):

According to different resources (for example [here](https://truesteamachievements.com/game/Making-History-II-The-War-of-the-World/achievements) and [here](https://www.exophase.com/game/making-history-ii-the-war-of-the-world-steam/achievements/)), the achievement is:

> **Early Defeat** Game Over in under 10 turns